# Running multiple commands after docker create

Tags: docker

I want to make a script run a series of commands in a Docker container and then copy a file out. If I use `docker run` to do this, I don't get back the container ID, which I would need for the `docker cp`. (I could try and hack it out of `docker ps`, but that seems risky.)

It seems that I should be able to

1. Create the container with `docker create` (which returns the container ID).
2. Run the commands.
3. Copy the file out.

But I don't know how to get step 2. to work. `docker exec` only works on running containers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, all you need is docker "`run` `exec` & `cp`" -

For example -

1. Create container with a name `--name` with `docker run` -

   `$ docker run --name bang -dit alpine`
2. Run few commands using `exec` -

   `$ docker exec -it bang sh -c "ls -l"`
3. Copy a file using `docker cp` -

   `$ docker cp bang:/etc/hosts ./`
4. Stop the container using `docker stop` -

   `$ docker stop bang`

Comment: It was the `--name` that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is `Dockerfile` and then build the image from it and run the container using the newly built image. For more information u can refer to 
[this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/)

A "standard" content of a dockerfile might be something like below:

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Ubuntu Software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install nginx, php-fpm and supervisord from ubuntu repository
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm supervisor && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Define the ENV variable
ENV nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
ENV nginx_conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ENV supervisor_conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

#Copy supervisor configuration
COPY supervisord.conf ${supervisor_conf}


# Configure Services and Port
COPY start.sh /start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Comment: I don't have any trouble building my image or running it. The problem is getting the container ID.

Comment: you can specify a name for the container before-hand `docker run --name compassionate_darwin nginx` and using the specified named on `docker cp` `compassionate_darwin:/tmp/foo/myfile.txt` instead of using the docker container id